# I'm trying to run a query in C# but its not working, though the query is correct

Tags: c#, sqlite

```
sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO community_market" +
           "VALUES (" + a.transaction_id + ",'" + a.community_name + "'," + 
                    a.community_id + ",'" + a.item_name + "'," +
                    a.item_quantity + "," + a.price + ");";
```

This is the query I am trying to run, the error I get is:

> SqliteSyntaxException: near "1": syntax error
>   Mono.Data.SqliteClient.SqliteCommand.GetNextStatement (IntPtr pzStart, System.IntPtr& pzTail, System.IntPtr& pStmt)
>   Mono.Data.SqliteClient.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader (CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean want_results, System.Int32& rows_affected)
>   Mono.Data.SqliteClient.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader (CommandBehavior behavior)
>   Mono.Data.SqliteClient.SqliteCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader (CommandBehavior behavior)
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader ()
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader ()

Could use some help

Comment: You should really use parameters instead. This code is open for sql injection.

Comment: Also, step through your code and put a break point after the sqlQuery variable is populated and before it is executed.  Give us the contents of the sqlQuery variable and the issue will probably be a lot more obvious

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you forgot a space in between `community_market` and `VALUES`:

```
sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO community_market " +
"VALUES("+a.transaction_id+",'"+ a.community_name+"',"+ 
a.community_id+",'"+ a.item_name+"',"+ a.item_quantity+","+a.price+");";
```

Also, [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) may be of some interest.

Comment: No problem! Glad to help.  If this fixed your issue feel free to mark the answer as accepted :-)